# Collection View cell dynamic height on the basis of image url

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

What is best way to show Collection View cell dynamic height on the basis of image url.

Should we scaled image while uploading image on server or scale image while loading image in cell?

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack overflow.
You can provide default images size when you are loading images and once you download it you can change collectionView cell size based on image size.

Comment: you can send image dimension(size*width) to your server while uploading image so it can be available at download Api.based on Dimension you can Set cell height.